# Design Patterns used in Eclipse GEF

Tags: eclipse-gef

Can anyone summarize the design patterns used in Eclipse GEF? I see that someone has done a perfect job on Eclipse platform and JDK. It would be very helpful for learning GEF if design patterns are illustrated.

For example, EditPartFactory is a typical factory pattern. GEF itself implements the MVC design.

A class hierarchy diagram is also very helpful.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief summary from GEF wiki.

- Factory: Creating models from palette, creating EditParts and creating Figures
- Observer: Typically a controller (EditPart) listening on Model and View
- Command: To implement Undo and Redo functions
- Strategy: EditParts can install and remove EditPolicies dynamically
- Chain of responsibility: To decide which EditPolicy should handle a Request